# Set superscript and subscript in formatted text in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, subscript, superscript, formatted-text

How can I set some text as subscript/superscript in `FormattedText` in WPF?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You use [Typography.Variants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.variants.aspx):

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>Normal Text</Run>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">Superscript Text</Run>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">Subscript Text</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: There are some known bugs with this, at least as of .Net 4.0: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f375a41b-2c36-4e51-8f6b-7ed828431412.  Don't know if it is fixed in .Net 4.5.

Comment: if some one get this bug with Win7 look at this link to fix it support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838

Comment: It should be noted that the default UI font for Windows (and WPF) supports neither subscripts nor superscripts prior to Windows 8.

Answer (score 19):

You can use something like `<TextBlock>5x<Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript">4</Run> + 4</TextBlock>`.

However, as far as I know, you will have to reduce the font-size yourself.

Comment: Is it normal that after each run a space is added? It works fine otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, best solution

Comment: the space is a known common problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090084/how-to-get-rid-of-whitespace-between-runs-in-textblock

Answer (score 19):

It's interesting to note that for some characters (m<sup>2</sup>, m<sup>3</sup>, etc) a superscript is not needed, but the unicode character can be used. For example:

```
<Run Text=" m&#x00B3;" />
```

This would show m<sup>3</sup>.

Comment: See wikipedia for a complete overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Answer (score 12):

I used a layout transform, because `Typography.Variants` often doesn't work:

```
<TextBlock Text="MyAmazingProduct"/>
 <TextBlock Text="TM">
  <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
   <!-- Typography.Variants="Superscript" didn't work -->
   <TransformGroup>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".75" ScaleY=".75"/>
    <TranslateTransform Y="-5"/>
   </TransformGroup>
  </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
 </TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Version, StringFormat={} v{0}}"/>
```

The advantage of using a `LayoutTransform` is that it is insensitive to the fontsize. If the fontsize is changed afterwards, this superscript works where explicit FontSize setting breaks.

Comment: Marvelous - this is a rather neat and configurable solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Typography.Variants works only for **open type fonts**. If you dont like your superscripts/subscripts going outside the height of actual text then you can use something like the following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Margin="0,5,0,0">1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontSize="30">H</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontSize="10" Margin="0,20,0,0">2</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you need this to work with FormattedText *specifically*, or you mean derivations of Inline, but the following will work on Inlines, even if Typography.Variants="Superscript" fails to work.

```
TextRange selection = new TextRange(document.ContentStart, document.ContentEnd);
selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.BaselineAlignmentProperty, BaselineAlignment.Superscript);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This fails miserably in my tests, based on RichTextBox and otherwise successful with bold, italic, underline, font family/color/size. I use the same .ApplyPropertyValue() with all of those. I useToggleButton's so I verify the alignment is set and remembered, but without visual effect.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only thing that worked for me. It also gives you more control over the alignment and font size.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="17">
    3 x 3<Run FontSize="6pt" BaselineAlignment="TextTop">2</Run>)
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting for superscript works fine with the following code:

```
<TextBlock Text="(cm"  />
<TextBlock ><Span BaselineAlignment="Top" FontSize="8">2</Span></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text=")" />
```

Setting the Baseallignment for subscript in the Span tag did not work for me.
I tried the following code and it worked fine.

```
  <TextBlock Text="H"  />
  <TextBlock Text="2" Margin="-2,0,-2,0" TextBlock.LineHeight="3" >   
  <TextBlock Text="O" />
```