# Subscript / superscript in FormattedText class?

Tags: wpf, subscript, superscript, formatted-text

I'm creating Text using the FormattedText class - but how can I subscript oder superscript Text when using this class? I found solution on how to do this when using a TextBlock, but I'm using FormattedText and not the TextBlock ): Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Can you post the solution you found for TextBlock. Will be helpful for others and may also help to solve your problem.

Comment: Hello akjoshi, have a look at Johnstone's answer. Additionaly please note, you need to use a font that supports it, like Palatino Linotype.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`FormattedText` can't do subscript/superscript - but `TextFormatter` can.

`TextFormatter` is a low level API, you need to write a lot of code to use it - but most of the code is just subclassing all the classes used to pass formatting parameters int `TextFormatter`.

### How to use TextFormatter

`TextFormatter` takes a `TextSource` object and produces multiple `TextLine` objects (one for each line), the `TextLine.Draw` method can then be used to draw the line to a drawing context.

The `TextSource` class is abstract, you have to subclass it and override the `GetTextRun` method that simply returns a `TextRun` object that's in the character position provided.

`TextRun` is also abstract - but it does have subclasses you can use - the interesting class is `TextCharacters` that contains a string and formatting information.

The formatting information is in a `TextRunProperties` object, unfortunately, this is another abstract class you have to subclass.

`TextRunProperties` has a `TypographyProperties` property of type `TextRunTypographyProperties`.

`TextRunTypographyProperties` is yet another abstract class you need to subclass.

And finally `TextRunTypographyProperties` has the `Variants` property you can use like the TextBlock example.

### Code Example

Here is the minimal code I could write to draw superscript text:

First, Our TextRunProperties and TextRunTypographyProperties that can return superscript font variant:

```
class CustomTextRunProperties : TextRunProperties
{
    private bool _superscript;
    public CustomTextRunProperties(bool superscript)
    {
        _superscript = superscript;
    }
    public override System.Windows.Media.Brush BackgroundBrush
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override CultureInfo CultureInfo
    {
        get { return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture; }
    }

    public override double FontHintingEmSize
    {
        get { return 22; }
    }

    public override double FontRenderingEmSize
    {
        get { return 22; }
    }

    public override Brush ForegroundBrush
    {
        get { return Brushes.Black; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection TextDecorations
    {
        get { return new System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection(); }
    }

    public override System.Windows.Media.TextEffectCollection TextEffects
    {
        get { return new TextEffectCollection(); }
    }

    public override System.Windows.Media.Typeface Typeface
    {
        get { return new Typeface("Calibri"); }
    }

    public override TextRunTypographyProperties TypographyProperties
    {
        get
        {
            return new CustomTextRunTypographyProperties(_superscript);
        }
    }

}

class CustomTextRunTypographyProperties : TextRunTypographyProperties
{
    private bool _superscript;

    public CustomTextRunTypographyProperties(bool superscript)
    {
        _superscript = superscript;
    }

    public override int AnnotationAlternates
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override bool CapitalSpacing
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.FontCapitals Capitals
    {
        get { return FontCapitals.Normal; }
    }

    public override bool CaseSensitiveForms
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool ContextualAlternates
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool ContextualLigatures
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override int ContextualSwashes
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override bool DiscretionaryLigatures
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool EastAsianExpertForms
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.FontEastAsianLanguage EastAsianLanguage
    {
        get { return FontEastAsianLanguage.Normal; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.FontEastAsianWidths EastAsianWidths
    {
        get { return FontEastAsianWidths.Normal; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.FontFraction Fraction
    {
        get { return FontFraction.Normal; }
    }

    public override bool HistoricalForms
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool HistoricalLigatures
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool Kerning
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool MathematicalGreek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.FontNumeralAlignment NumeralAlignment
    {
        get { return FontNumeralAlignment.Normal; }
    }

    public override System.Windows.FontNumeralStyle NumeralStyle
    {
        get { return FontNumeralStyle.Normal; }
    }

    public override bool SlashedZero
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StandardLigatures
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override int StandardSwashes
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override int StylisticAlternates
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet1
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet10
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet11
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet12
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet13
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet14
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet15
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet16
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet17
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet18
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet19
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet2
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet20
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet3
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet4
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet5
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet6
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet7
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet8
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool StylisticSet9
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override FontVariants Variants
    {
        get { return _superscript ? FontVariants.Superscript: FontVariants.Normal; }
    }
}
```

And a similar class for paragraph formatting (takes from MSDN TextFormatter sample):

```
class GenericTextParagraphProperties : TextParagraphProperties
{
    public GenericTextParagraphProperties(
       FlowDirection flowDirection,
       TextAlignment textAlignment,
       bool firstLineInParagraph,
       bool alwaysCollapsible,
       TextRunProperties defaultTextRunProperties,
       TextWrapping textWrap,
       double lineHeight,
       double indent)
    {
        _flowDirection = flowDirection;
        _textAlignment = textAlignment;
        _firstLineInParagraph = firstLineInParagraph;
        _alwaysCollapsible = alwaysCollapsible;
        _defaultTextRunProperties = defaultTextRunProperties;
        _textWrap = textWrap;
        _lineHeight = lineHeight;
        _indent = indent;
    }

    public override FlowDirection FlowDirection
    {
        get { return _flowDirection; }
    }

    public override TextAlignment TextAlignment
    {
        get { return _textAlignment; }
    }

    public override bool FirstLineInParagraph
    {
        get { return _firstLineInParagraph; }
    }

    public override bool AlwaysCollapsible
    {
        get { return _alwaysCollapsible; }
    }

    public override TextRunProperties DefaultTextRunProperties
    {
        get { return _defaultTextRunProperties; }
    }

    public override TextWrapping TextWrapping
    {
        get { return _textWrap; }
    }

    public override double LineHeight
    {
        get { return _lineHeight; }
    }

    public override double Indent
    {
        get { return _indent; }
    }

    public override TextMarkerProperties TextMarkerProperties
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public override double ParagraphIndent
    {
        get { return _paragraphIndent; }
    }

    private FlowDirection _flowDirection;
    private TextAlignment _textAlignment;
    private bool _firstLineInParagraph;
    private bool _alwaysCollapsible;
    private TextRunProperties _defaultTextRunProperties;
    private TextWrapping _textWrap;
    private double _indent;
    private double _paragraphIndent;
    private double _lineHeight;
}
```

Now TextSource implementation:

```
public class CustomTextSourceRun
{
    public string Text;
    public bool IsSuperscript;
    public bool IsEndParagraph;
    public int Length { get { return IsEndParagraph ? 1 : Text.Length; } }
}


class CustomTextSource : TextSource
{
    public List<CustomTextSourceRun> Runs = new List<CustomTextSourceRun>();

    public override TextRun GetTextRun(int textSourceCharacterIndex)
    {
        int pos = 0;
        foreach (var currentRun in Runs)
        {
            if (textSourceCharacterIndex < pos + currentRun.Length)
            {
                if (currentRun.IsEndParagraph)
                {
                    return new TextEndOfParagraph(1);
                }

                var props =
                    new CustomTextRunProperties(currentRun.IsSuperscript);

                return new TextCharacters(
                    currentRun.Text,
                    textSourceCharacterIndex - pos,
                    currentRun.Length - (textSourceCharacterIndex - pos),
                    props);


            }
            pos += currentRun.Length;
        }

        // Return an end-of-paragraph if no more text source.
        return new TextEndOfParagraph(1);
    }

    public override TextSpan<CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange> GetPrecedingText(int textSourceCharacterIndexLimit)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }

    public override int GetTextEffectCharacterIndexFromTextSourceCharacterIndex(int textSourceCharacterIndex)
    {
        throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            int r = 0;
            foreach (var currentRun in Runs)
            {
                r += currentRun.Length;
            }
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

And all that's left to do is initialize out CustomTextSource and draw the text:

```
     var textStore = new CustomTextSource();
     textStore.Runs.Add(new CustomTextSourceRun() { Text = "3" });
     textStore.Runs.Add(new CustomTextSourceRun() { Text = "rd", IsSuperscript = true });
     textStore.Runs.Add(new CustomTextSourceRun() { IsEndParagraph = true });
     textStore.Runs.Add(new CustomTextSourceRun() { Text = "4" });
     textStore.Runs.Add(new CustomTextSourceRun() { Text = "th", IsSuperscript = true });

     int textStorePosition = 0;
     System.Windows.Point linePosition = new System.Windows.Point(0, 0); 

     textDest = new DrawingGroup();
     DrawingContext dc = textDest.Open();

     TextFormatter formatter = TextFormatter.Create();

     while (textStorePosition < textStore.Length)
     {
        using (TextLine myTextLine = formatter.FormatLine(
            textStore,
            textStorePosition,
            96*6,
            new GenericTextParagraphProperties(FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                TextAlignment.Left,true,false, new CustomTextRunProperties(false), TextWrapping.Wrap,
                30,0), null))
        {
            myTextLine.Draw(dc, linePosition, InvertAxes.None);
            textStorePosition += myTextLine.Length;
            linePosition.Y += myTextLine.Height;
        }
     }

     dc.Close();
```

And that's it - we have superscript text in a drawing context.

Comment: Worth mentioning that only fonts with superscript/subscript variants will support this method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.fontvariants.aspx - the same problem that applies with using a TextBlock.  This answer the closest you will get though!

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply, Nir. I yet didn't have the chance to test it, but looks very promising and is a great TextFormatter example. Will get back to you / this! Selected as answer and bounty awarded!

Answer (score 0):

There simply isn't a way with `FormattedText`, see the complete reference here:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext_members.aspx

You can do with it `TextBlock`, as you have already discovered:

> [Set superscript and subscript in formatted text in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095583/set-superscript-and-subscript-in-formatted-text-in-wpf)

Or you could simply make the `FormattedText` smaller (`SetFontSize`) and position it above/below manually.

If you could give some more context as to the situation you are using the `FormattedText`, or the problem you are trying to solve, or why you cannot use a `TextBlock`, please post a reply to this answer and we will be happy to help with more specific examples.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Kieren. While your reply answers the original question, I decided to choose Nirs answer because of his detailed "alternative". Hope you don't mind and thanks again for your answer!

Comment: The reasion why I don't want to use a TextBlock is, that I need to position text exactly and TextBlock always has some kind of padding in it, even if set to 0.