# C# Write subscript text without unicode

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How can  I write a subscript text without using Unicode
for example I want write H<sub>2</sub>0 without writing "H" + \x2082O

Comment: If you're using WPF controls, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095583/set-superscript-and-subscript-in-formatted-text-in-wpf and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.variants.aspx

Comment: but can I make changes from code?

Comment: Can you show the code you have now, in which you want to have super & sub-scripts?