# How to superscript a string in Application.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I already know how to do it in wpf as

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="359,10,0,0" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75">
    <Run>X</Run>
    <Run BaselineAlignment="Superscript" FontSize="8">4</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2095699/3430839), or in the code as

```
string area;
area = "mm\xB2";
testTblock.Text = area;
```

But how you can do it in Application.Resources?  As

```
<Application.Resources>
<System:String x:Key="area">
     //what should be here?
</System:String>
```

so that I could apply it to the DynamicResource as

```
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource area}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In text value use Hexadecimal value encoding:

```
<system:String x:Key="myValue">
    mm&#xB2;
</system:String>
```