# How can I superscript specific characters a wpf string binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to superscript a wpf binding, for example:
`c#`:

```
public string PolynomialAsString = "10x^2 + 3x - 1";
```

`xaml`:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding PolynomialAsString}" />
```

To be displayed as: 10x² + 3x - 1 in the wpf application.

The only ways I have found to do this online hardcode the position of the superscipt in the `xaml` like so:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>Normal Text</Run>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">Superscript Text</Run>
    <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">Subscript Text</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

But I would like do this dynamically, as I do not know the positions of the superscripts.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: replace ^ with &#x00B as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41223500/3201354

Comment: @Jignesh I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work when it is bound to the `TextBlock`, also that unicode pattern is only consistent for ^2 & ^3

Comment: Try one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071856/1136211

Comment: You could always derive your own SuperScriptTextBlock which parses and adds the inlines itself when the binding updates. I've done similar for highlighting text. Pain the arse though. Can't believe there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the [wpf-math](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math) library.

Here is an example:

'c#':

```
public string PolynomialAsString = "10x^2 + 3x - 1";
```

'xaml':

```
<Window ... xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfMath.Controls;assembly=WpfMath">
    <controls:FormulaControl Grid.Row="1" Formula="{Binding PolynomialAsString}" />
</ Window>
```