# Render superscript in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, .net-4.7

Here’s the code:

```
static readonly char[] s_expChar = "eE".ToCharArray();

static void setValue( TextBlock target, double val )
{
    string text = val.ToString();
    int indE = text.IndexOfAny( s_expChar );
    if( indE > 0 )
    {
        string normal = text.Substring( 0, indE ) + "·10";

        string ss = text.Substring( indE + 1 );
        if( ss.StartsWith( "0" ) )
            ss = ss.Substring( 1 );
        else if( ss.StartsWith( "-0" ) )
            ss = "-" + ss.Substring( 2 );

        target.Inlines.Clear();
        target.Inlines.Add( new Run( normal ) );
        Run rSuper = new Run( ss );
        Typography.SetVariants( rSuper, FontVariants.Superscript );
        target.Inlines.Add( rSuper );
    }
    else
    {
        target.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

[image]

As you see, vertical alignment of the `-` character is broken, seems not affected by `FontVariants.Superscript`. How to fix?

In debugger in live visual tree, I see 2 runs with the correct values, i.e. the second one has text `-6` including the `-`

Comment: `Typography.Variants` is notoriously buggy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095583/set-superscript-and-subscript-in-formatted-text-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

`Typography.Variants` should be used with the right fonts and the right characters. So for example this piece of XAML can work not properly:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20">
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="2e" />
        <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="-3" />
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

As you noticed, the "-" symbol is not aligned as supposed. Indeed `Typography.Variants` works just for an [OpenType font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) (I suggest you *Palatino Linotype* or *Segoe UI*). Moreover is not correct to use the minus symbol with a `Superscript` typography variant: the right character is called [superscript minus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/207b/index.htm) (`&#8315;` is its decimal representation).

So the correct XAML will be:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI">
    <TextBlock.Inlines>
        <Run Text="2e" />
        <Run Typography.Variants="Superscript" Text="&#8315;3" />
    </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

and it will be displayed as supposed. I hope it can help you.