# Binding formatted text to templated TextBlock

Tags: wpf

I have an external control which displays a layout formed from a label and an input control. My label requires special formatting (subscript) but it currently only supports direct text.

So my approach is to create a custom `TextBlock` implementation, which exposes a new `InlineContent` dependency property that, once set, converts the content and adds it to it's actual `Inlines` collection.

For the layout control I add a custom `DataTemplate` which binds the label content to the `InlineContent` property of my custom text block.

`ExtendedTextBlock.cs`:

```
private static void InlinesChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(d is ExtendedTextBlock b)) return;

    b.Inlines.Clear();
    if (e.NewValue is InlineCollection collection)
        b.Inlines.AddRange(collection);
    if (e.NewValue is Span span)
        b.Inlines.AddRange(span.Inlines);
    if (e.NewValue is Run run)
        b.Inlines.Add(run);
    if (e.NewValue is string str)
        b.Inlines.Add(new Run(str));
}
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <controls:ExtendedTextBlock InlineContent="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Label:

```
<dxlc:LayoutItem.Label>
    <Span>
        <Run>Right (R</Run>
        <Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">R</Run>
        <Run>)</Run>
    </Span>
</dxlc:LayoutItem.Label>
```

This works fine for regular text (strings) but when I set a `Span` as my label's content, then I get the following exception:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'
>   Inner Exception:
>   InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

This occurs in line `b.Inlines.AddRange(span.Inlines)`. Why so? I don't understand which collection changes.

Binding directly to `Text` does not work. Then I only see 'System.Documents.Text.Span` but not the span actually being rendered.

Comment: Two notes. Checking `if (!(d is ExtendedTextBlock b))` is redundant. The property can not be set on any DependencyObject that is not an ExtendedTextBlock. Better use a cast to get an `InvalidCastException` in case the code is used in an unexpected way. Also use `else if` instead of a chain of `if` statements.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well, I wasn't sure about that. The if's were mainly because I just quickly tried around and normally only one of these cases can occur at the same time, but you're right nonetheless. Changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why that happens, but copying `Span.Inlines` to a new collection solves the problem:

```
using System.Linq;
...

b.Inlines.AddRange(span.Inlines.ToList());
```

Comment: It does work but the text is displayed without any effects (no subscript) for some reason. I also tried adding the span directly, but then I get an exception saying `Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.`. How can I preserve the subscript, though?

Comment: Yeah I just tried it. It only works for numbers, but not for letters.

Comment: You need a font that supports it. MS Docs samples use `FontFamily="Palatino Linotype"`.

Comment: No, one of the comments in the [marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095583/set-superscript-and-subscript-in-formatted-text-in-wpf) says that there's a known bug (sadly the link to MS Connect doesn't work, so I don't know if that is the same bug we're talking about). Nonetheless it works when setting `BaselineAlignment` property instead of the attached `Typography.Variants` property.

Comment: Well, for me it works with `FontFamily="Palatino Linotype"`.